# how do I create a program that uses a for loop to print the first 1000 perfect squares?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is what I have so far. I have to write a for loop that prints the first 1000 perfect squares and also determines the time of execution. the timer is working but I don't really know how to show the 1000 perfect squares.

```
public class WhileLoop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time_start, time_finish;
    time_start = time();

    int i;

    for( i =0; i< 1000; i++){ 

{
    System.out.print("");
}
System.out.println(i);
```

}

```
    time_finish = time();

    System.out.println(time_finish - time_start + " milli seconds");





    }
    public static long time(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

}

Comment: And what exactly is stopping you?

Comment: The question is low quality and it doesn't demonstrate attempt or reasearch at this stage. Strongly recommend you edit the question to demonstrate what the attempt has been and problem you are facing, or remove question.

Comment: If a perfect square is defined as `y := x * x` where `y` and `x` are both integers, then, to compute the first 1000 perfect squares, you compute `x * x` for `x in [0, 999]`. The iteration over `x` is expressed by the loop. So all you have to add is `i * i` somewhere in your loop. The question is what you will do with the computed numbers? Keep in mind that, if you print them as you compute them, the execution time (that you compute) will be much larger, since i/o access is very slow. Don't measure the time of the i/o access if you want to measure solely the computation time.

Answer (score 2):

You got to break down the problem 1 by 1. Long story short. You should do the following:

1. Get Start Time
2. Print 1*1
3. Print 2*2
4. Print 3*3 ... to first 1000 squares
5. Print Total Execution Time

Here are the code snippets you will need to get this to work:

Then using the tools that Java provides. You can:

1. Retrieve Current Time (Store this into a `startTime` variable)
2. Loop through 1000 elements and print results
3. Retrieve Current Time (Compare this with the `startTime` to get total `RunTime`)

I don't want to give away too much. So, hopefully this will provide a good push in the right direction.